# Writing an api-doc for Swagger

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui, api-doc

I'm trying to use the Swagger UI, and it says that I should begin by writing an api-doc that describes the exact api for a REST api. The problem is that I have no idea what this means. Is this document written in plain English? Or is there a certain format that will be able to generate the UI?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swagger is a specification for describing REST APIs. Documentation of the specification can be found here - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec.

Generally, there are two ways to document your API. If you already have an existing API with code, you can use any of the existing libraries (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec#additional-libraries) to integrate into your code and generate documentation at run time. Some of those libraries also offer offline generation of such docs.

If you're looking to design an API, or would rather not integrate another library into your application, you can use https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor either locally or with the online version - http://editor.swagger.io.

Once you have the documentation, you can use Swagger UI to visualize and test it.